# Is it possible to redraw a single Mesh in WebGl?

Tags: graphics, 2d, webgl

I'm having code as follows:

```
let arr = new Float32Array([-0.4, 0.3, -0.4, 0, 0.3, -0.2,
        -0.5, -0.25,
        0.7, 0.25,
        0.9, -0.7    
]);
let position_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, position_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, arr, gl.STATIC_DRAW)

gl.vertexAttribPointer(position_location, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0 , 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position_location);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
```

If i want to change the second triangle (initial vertex `-0.5, -0.25` in the `arr`), is there a way, to reach a gpu buffer, and tell him to redraw the vertices with an offset 3, and length of 3 ? So my first triangle wouldn't be redrawn?

Answer (score 0):

It's called instanced drawing in webgl. Maybe for somebody would be helpful.